# How to configure JsonDeserializer in consumer kafka

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, jackson, spring-kafka

How to configure JsonDeserializer in consumer kafka

I can do JsonSerializer in producer and pass an object but I wanted to do the same in consumer with JsonDeserializer but I'm getting an error

```
Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at com.example.userinsert.UserInsertApplication.main(UserInsertApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:823) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:664) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createRawConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:483) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:451) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumerWithAdjustedProperties(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:427) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:394) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:371) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:795) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:363) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:461) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:209) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:461) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:383) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:328) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3578) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2754) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:392) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:399) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:434) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:419) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:715) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

The producer configuration:

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
#spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

My class:

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;

@Override
public void createKfaka(Object object) 
{
    logger.info(String.format("Message sent -> %s", object.toString()));
    this.kafkaTemplate.send("user", object);

}
```

The consumer configuration:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties[spring.json.value.default.type]=com.example.Invoice
spring.kafka.consumer.properties[spring.json.trusted.packages]=*
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=users
```

My class:

```
@Override
@KafkaListener(topics = "user" , groupId = "users")
public void consume(Object message) 
{
    logger.info(String.format("Message recieved -> %s", message));
    //mongoTemplate.insert(message, "user");
    
}
```

My dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

New error:

```
Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at com.example.userinsert.UserInsertApplication.main(UserInsertApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:823) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:664) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createRawConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:483) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:451) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumerWithAdjustedProperties(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:427) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:394) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:371) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:795) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:363) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:461) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:209) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:461) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:383) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:328) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.Invoice
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.setupTarget(JsonDeserializer.java:491) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.configure(JsonDeserializer.java:410) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:716) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.Invoice
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.setupTargetType(JsonDeserializer.java:515) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.setupTarget(JsonDeserializer.java:483) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this error?

Comment: Have you added Jackson databind to your dependencies?

Comment: yes i have @OneCricketeer

Answer (score 0):

It might be a version issue with your dependencies. Try adding the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Can you also share your full dependencies list? Your application properties look fine as well as the other info.

**EDIT**
As the the latest error, I think we moved a bit further and I believe you are missing a configuration class. It will be pretty much like this:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(
          ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
          bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(
          ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, 
          groupId);
        props.put(
          ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
          StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(
          ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
          StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
```

Comment: I updated the question with my dependencies

Comment: I do not see the dependencies I listed, does that make a difference? Can you add them?

Comment: I added it but it still gives an error I added it to the question as "new error"

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does it look like your Kafka Config class, something similar to this? https://github.com/lokeshgupta1981/Kafka-Tutorials/blob/master/spring-kafka-java-config/src/main/java/com/howtodoinjava/kafka/demo/config/KafkaConsumerConfig.java You shared what it seems to be your service, rather than the consumer config class.

Comment: Also, it seems to complain now about your Invoice model class: ```Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.Invoice``` can you share that too?

Comment: I don't have any configuration class

Comment: I have added an example config class. See the github repository I have shared, that has a basic demo for setting up a consumer and producer. See if it helper

Comment: I'll see later then I'll give you feedback

Comment: This documentation does not talk about creating a configuration class https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#messaging.kafka

Comment: I think you need to rather look into this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/

Comment: A config class isn't necessary. Spring boot will automatically initialize one

Comment: Does it not work because the producer is in a microservice and the consumer is in another. Receive as a string on the consumer I can

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.usercreate.dto.AddressUserDto usercreate is the microservice producer